# How to do a Cronjob via SSH on Linux

Tags: linux, ssh, cron

I have a linux server where I want to install a Cron.

I was given a URL, and by visiting this URL (GET request), it will automatically rebuild a new sitemap for my website.

Basically, I want a cron to go to this URL once a day, thus my sitemap will be regenerated once a day

I'm not sure what info I need to give you regarding cron on my server...but when I go to /etc/ I can see...
cron.d , cron.daily , cron.deny , cron.hourly , cron.monthy , crontab

one other thing, when i visit the GET request url myself, it takes a while before the page loads. It takes about 1-2 minutes and then a "SITEMAP COMPLETE" page appears. So the cron will have to stay at it for the entire duration until that message appears, else the sitemap will only partially regenerate.

Edit *** I think I found the answer, can someone please confirm of this is correct ???
In crontab -e, I enter:

0 0 1 * *  /usr/bin/wget -q -O - "http://www.domain.com/GET-REQUEST"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use 'wget' or 'curl', so yes your example is correct. You can ether add it with `crontab -e` or add the line to /etc/crontab (But add which user to run as)

Comment: If i use the wget, will it save a file on my server somewhere everytime the cron is run?

Comment: @Virendar Yes, if you use CURL it won't (Unless you specify the -O flag, but don't do that). Just set the command as `curl http://yourdomain/script.php` and that will download the file but not save it

Comment: @Virendar you could use *wget* with *--spider* as argument and that will make don't save the output

Comment: hmm, so wget -q -O should be changed to either wget --spider or curl ?

Comment: @Verendar Ether use `wget --spider http://yourdomain/script.php` or `curl http://yourdomain/script.php`, not both =) I prefer CURL, purely because the syntax is easier, there's probably a performance comparison somewhere but it's more down to personal choice, which one you find easier to use.

Comment: @Virendar Yes, that would work fine. I just used script.php as an example, I probably confused the issue more than I should have done. If you were having to use /usr/bin/wget rather than just `wget` you'll probably need to use /usr/bin/curl instead of just `curl` so it gets the right path